# DLL's in a ASP.NET Application and SourceSafe/Sharing between computers

Tags: asp.net, dll, gac

I have an application that uses currently two DLL's for external libraries (AjaxControlToolkit is one of them)

I was wondering the best way for a colleague of mine to check out my application from our SourceSafe database and use these libraries.

I don't know much about utlising external libraries other then really adding them as a reference to a project and have very little knowledge about the GAC.

This thread mentioned about putting them into the GAC on each developers machines. http://forums.devx.com/showthread.php?t=151411

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy them to the web applications /bin folder. When you upload to source control (SourceSafe/SVN/etc), they will be available to be shared. This will override what is found in the GAC.

Additionally, you can still develop your projects with the DLLs registered in the GAC. Each developer can still register the DLLs with the GAC independently.